# The background image is not loading

Tags: android

I used to use `android:background` tag in a linear layout for placing background image in my app. Due to some upgrades in android studio during my project, whenever I try to use the background tag again, the gradle builds Ok, but the app doesn't run on my device, and the debugger says

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(xxxxxxxxbytes) bitmap.

I tried reducing the size and the resolution of the image, but nothing seems to be working. What do I do?

Comment: What is the size of your image ?

Comment: size as in filesize

Comment: Android apps have different RAM limitations based on the device. I suggest creating a low-res (20kb or so) with paint and try again. If the error persists, it's another issue. Maybe it ran out of memory and this image was the final 'straw' at which your phone/emulator decided the RAM usage became too high.